# Loop-de- loop waste pipe

Tags: plumbing, drain, pvc

I replaced an old metal pipe and p-trap with 2 inch PVC for a shower drain.  I was only able to fit the new pvc p-trap if I made a loop-de-loop. Is this a good solution?

[image: side view]
[image: bottom view]

Comment: The confusion below stems from the fact that one of your photos is upside-down. Or maybe both are severely tilted. In any event, since gravity is a factor, you should really post new photos with a proper perspective.

Comment: You are right, until then, the first picture is a side view exactly like tester101's diagram the second picture is a view from the bottom looking up. its in a tight spot in the ceiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a double trap, unless I'm mistaken on how the water flows through this drain.

[image]

I've scribbled in where water will sit in the pipe, which clearly shows two traps.

The best option would be to go from the upper 90 of the P-trap, directly into the outlet pipe.

[image]

When you rebuild the trap, you should use a u-bend with a cleanout.

[image]

Comment: their is not enough room above to do that

Comment: If you can't move the trap up, you have to move the outlet pipe down.  It's difficult to provide a solution that will work for you, since it's hard to see exactly what's going on.  Could you provide a few more photos of the area? Also, providing a detailed diagram that shows how much space is available above and below the drain, that would be helpful as well. It looks to me that the drain drops down a few inches from the tub outlet, before it enters the trap.  Why can't the trap be up closer to the tub outlet?

Comment: if the second trap is legitimate the one made of 90 and 45 degree turns i can use just that as my p-trap but a normal p-trap will stick down into the ceiling below please note i have made a new question asking if the second trap is a good p-trap

Comment: @joe looking at it again... why can't you just go from the upper 90 of the first trap, to the outlet pipe? I've updated my answer, to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Testor101 thanks, that might just do it.  Are you sure that will not create a s-trap as it will turn down after the original p-trap?  It will probably take me two weeks before i can try this out.

Comment: there is not enough room for a u bend with a cleanout!

Comment: How far away from the trap does it turn down?

Comment: thank you I went "from the upper 90 of the P-trap, directly into the outlet pipe".  It both works and fits in the ceiling.

Comment: @joe mind posting a photo of the finished product?